# Error message running arara from MikTeX 2.9

Tags: arara, miktex2.9

I am trying to run `arara`  on a Windows 10 (x64) system from `MikTeX 2.9` as follows in this MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

What I get is the following error message:

```
arara.exe: MikTeX encountered an internal error.
arara.exe: Data: index="4294967295"
```

`arara` is installed in my system, and I have checked it is in the system's path by issuing the "arara" command from the command line to an affiramtive response: the `arara` introduction message is displayed in the command line window.

Any hints to solve this issue will be welcome.

Comment: I might need to investigate, I suspect it's something related to the MiKTeX wrapper around `arara` rather than the Java binary itself. Quick Q: was it working before?

Comment: what happens when you run `pdflatex yourfile` on the command line? Did you install arara with the miktex package manager?

Comment: @Paulo Cereda: I first tried it in an earlier MikTeX version on Windows XP and it worked fine. That was a few years back when `arara` was first issued. I didn't try it again until today.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: It works perfectly. Both from the command line and from WinEdt (8.0). And, yes, I installed (and reinstalled today, just in case) `arara` with the MikTeX package manager.

Comment: @Marcos: back to the drawing board. `:)` Does other tool like `latexmk` work? Perhaps if MiKTeX had an option to reinstall the "package", it could fix things that possibly got messed up...

Comment: Did you check with the update managers (user and admin) if there are updates?

Comment: Worth asking: `arara` requires Java, is it installed in your system?

Comment: @Paulo Cereda: `latexmk <myfile>` returns the same error message as `arara <myfile>`.

Comment: @Paulo Cereda: It is indeed. I work regularly with Java.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I installed today the most recent version of `arara` from my regular repository with the MikTeX manager.

Comment: Nice to hear you work with Java. `:)` It seems there might be some issue around the wrappers, as both `arara` and `latexmk` fail... @UlrikeFischer: any ideas?

Comment: No I didn't mean only arara. Did you check for other updates?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: On the run...

Comment: @PauloCereda latexmk is a perl script, arara java, so it sounds like a miktex problem and one check for updates.

Comment: @PauloCereda: Updating MikTeX... In the meantime, it is nice to work with Java. I absolutely love "TeX and friends", but it can so easily become quite frustrating (oops, read "challenging"). My Java experience feels like paradise in contrast.

Comment: You were both right. After updating MikTeX 2.9, `arara` is working. If any of you would provide an answer to check, I would happily it do so. Thank you so much to the two of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by an update. So I'm writing a more general answer:

`internal error` indicates a bug. And so the first step to handle this is to check if everything is up-to-date. This means check with both update managers (admin and user) for updates. If there are lot of updates open it is senseful to open the package manager (admin), synchronize and to check if they are uninstalled packages starting with `miktex` *before* actually getting the updates.

If the problem persists after the update you can make a bug report at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues.